# Material design nuxt integration

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, material-components-web

I'm new to Nuxt framework and i want to integrate the material design library in my project (the offical one : https://material.io/develop/web/).

I've made a plugin with this content :

```
import Vue from "vue"
import mdcAutoInit from "@material/auto-init"
import { MDCTextField } from "@material/textfield"
import { MDCTextFieldIcon } from "@material/textfield/icon"
import { MDCSelect } from "@material/select"
import { MDCFormField } from "@material/form-field"
import { MDCRadio } from "@material/radio"

function init() {
  /** Select */
  mdcAutoInit.register("select", MDCSelect)

  /** TextField */
  mdcAutoInit.register("textfield", MDCTextField)
  mdcAutoInit.register("textfieldIcon", MDCTextFieldIcon)

  /** Radio */
  mdcAutoInit.register("formfield", MDCFormField)
  mdcAutoInit.register("radio", MDCRadio)

  // /** Auto Init */
  mdcAutoInit.apply()
}

const plugin = {
  install(vm) {
    console.log("Installing")

    vm.component(MDCTextFieldIcon)
    vm.component(MDCTextField)
    vm.component(MDCSelect)
    vm.component(MDCFormField)
    vm.component(MDCRadio)

    init()
  }
}

if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.Vue) {
  window.Vue.use(plugin)
} else {
  Vue.use(plugin)
}
```

And i've added it in the plugin section in nuxt.config.js.

It seems to work when i load a page (the textfield animation is working for example) but when i change the page using nuxt-link the textfield are not initialized.

Does anyone knows how to make material design load the init function for each component loaded ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There's an npm package for [that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-vue-material).

Comment: Thanks for answering but i want to use the official library that contains all new material design elements (eg: textflieds)

Comment: This components you are trying to use e.g. @material/select are not vue components so your vue.component should be a vue component not some random stuff.
PS also your check at the end for window is totally not needed and should be just Vue.use(plugin).

PSS i suggest to use vuetify

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're using `mdcAutoInit`. Please see the [Material Design documentation](https://material.io/develop/web/components/auto-init/) regarding this utility. Pay especially close attention to mentions of running multiple times and new DOM elements.

Why? Because you're use Nuxt and therefore most likely building an SPA, which means your website isn't static. Why does a website not being static matter? Because auto-init attaches plain, non-reactive event listeners to existing DOM elements. What happens when Vue replaces those DOM elements via a re-render (e.g. a `v-if` condition changes)? The existing DOM elements have been destroyed along with their attached event listeners, and any new DOM elements have not yet been initialized through auto-init. Why not? Because the vanilla material design library is non-reactive, so Vue doesn't know what the heck to do with it, and auto-init assumes it's only going to be run once.

It appears that you need to run `window.mdc.autoInit(/* root */ document, () => {});` within an `updated()` and `mounted()` hook within every single one of your custom components that contains a material design component in order to ensure that the appropriate event listeners are attached as needed (and keep in mind that this will be a potentially fairly expensive operation depending on the total DOM size at runtime).

Or, if you'd like to avoid the headache altogether, use an existing material design framework or component library and simply export the components you want with your plugin. You can find a list of these frameworks and plugins at the [awesome-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue) GitHub repo.